# Monte Carlo tree search optimizations

Tags: algorithms, optimization, machine-learning

I am designing a algoritm for a game using a Monte Carlo tree search AI that I implemented. I play against another player and want to get the best move. Every time I do a move I completely build a new search tree and do as much iterations possible given a certain deadline. Is there a way to use the previous tree that I build or do I always have to build a tree every time I make a move.

our turn: calculate tree beginning from scratch using uct

otherplayer turn: his turn

our turn: calculate tree beginning from scratch using uct

Is there a way I can optimize this So i could do even more iterations/ be faster ?
like for exemple:

our turn first: calculate tree beginning from scratch using uct

otherplayer turn: his turn

our turn: use tree we already calculated in our first turn and do more iterations given the values

Or are there other optimalisations I could do?

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389700/why-does-monte-carlo-tree-search-reset-tree

Comment: (Zeroth improvement: use *improvement* where something gets better, but not optimal.)

Comment: @greybeard I don't realy get what you are trying to say, wouldn't I be able to do
first move: calculate tree from scratch
next move opponents:
second move: follow the path of first move and opponents move and begin not from scratch but from that node ?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster on *optimalisation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optimalisation) ([really](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realy)). Not forgetting something that took effort to know and may well be valuable sounds prudent. You may want to capitalise UCT, mention what it means here. Generally follow [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: m8 your comment isn't useful at all